# How to resolve promise function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can I show the result after the promise? I see the result in `console.log("the result is==>", result)` but under `promise.then` I don't see the console.

```js
const signIn = (password) => {
  var request = new DeviceAuthQuery();
  request.setPassword(password);
  let result;

  var response = client.authenticate(request, {}, (err, response) => {
    console.log("Request Sent 1111");
  });

  let promise = new Promise(() => {
    response.on('data', function(reply) {
      console.log('Data: 22222' + reply.getAuthjwt());
      result = reply.getAuthjwt();
      console.log("the result is==>", result)
      promise.resolve(true);
    });
  });

  promise.then(() => {
    console.log("the result ZZZZZ==>", result)
  })
```

Comment: Consider using the arguments in the Promise constructor (`new Promise((resolve, reject) =>`, rather than relying on the `promise` variable.

Comment: From your code, it's not immediately clear why promises are needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the callback result:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
   response.on('data', function(reply) {
     console.log('Data: 22222' + reply.getAuthjwt());
     result = reply.getAuthjwt();
     console.log("the result is==>", result)
     resolve(true);
   });
});

promise.then((result) => {
  console.log("the result ZZZZZ==>", result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the arguments in the function you provide to the Promise constructor in order to resolve/reject the promise. Then you just pass the data to those as arguments. Here's a basic example:

```js
const signIn = () => {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("Foo Bar");
    }, 2000)
  });

  promise.then((result) => {
    console.log("the result ZZZZZ==>", result)
  })
}

signIn();
```